# How to get access to the executed SQL queries in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: sql, zend-db, zend-framework3

How can you get access to all the SQL queries that are being executed by Zend Framework 3?

Answer (score 1):

In Zend Framework 3 you can use "profiling" to track the performance of the SQL queries. This can also be used to access the executed SQL queries.

In your database config set the `profiler = true` options on a certain adapter like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'db' => [
        'adapters' => [
            'adapter1' => [
                'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1',
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
                'profiler' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Then fetch the adapter (it is a service with corresponding name) and get the driver, get the profiler and the profiles. Profiles is an array containing all sql statements.

```
$adapter = $application->getServiceManager()->get('adapter1'); 
$profiles = $adapter->getDriver()->getProfiler()->getProfiles();
```

Every profile is an array with associative key "sql" where the raw query is stored.

```
$firstSqlQuery = $profiles[0]['sql'];
```